# How can Kubernetes help me deploy one app per client?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to Kubernetes, and after I've seen how huge it is I thought I'd ask for a bit of help.

The purpose of my company is to deploy a set of apps independantly for each of our clients. Say we have an app A, we want to deploy a first version for client 1, another version for client 2, etc. We will have a lot of clients in the future (maybe around 50). Of course we want to be able to manage them easily.

Which part of Kubernetes should I explore to achieve this, or if kubernetes is not fit for this what else should I consider ?

Thanks !

Comment: there is a "namespace" concept. maybe it can fit your needs. But if number of clients eventually goes far above 50, I think it's not a good practice

Answer (score 3):

There is concept in kubernetes as `namespaces` which are isolated with each other and provide the isolation between deployments in it.

so you can use and explore the namespaces in kubernetes which will help to isolate the client versions and deployments.

> if kubernetes is not fit for this what else should I consider ?

if donot think it may happen for your requirement kubernetes having lots of options for deployment for zero downtime in service, with kubernetes you can implement CI/CD so i think kubernetes will be easy to setup and manage any application.

Comment: I want to add on my own that for > 50 clients, maintaining isolation at the namespace level is rather difficult.

Comment: @Arslanbekov yes absolutley true but in that case he can devide deployments in namespace to manage or have to manage namespace that way. but donot think it is hard to manage it on kubernetes

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that !